# What kind of asymptote is this?

Tags: limits, asymptotics, approximation-theory

I was looking at Stirling's approximation and I came up with the following sort of asymptote:

$$f(x)=g(x+a(x))$$

where $a(x)\to0$ as $x\to\infty$.  I noticed this because, if we let $S(x)$ be Stirling's approximation,

$$x!-S(x)\to\infty,x\to\infty$$

But the horizontal difference tends to $0$ ie $x!=S(x+a(x))\implies a(x)\to0$ as $x\to\infty$.

What kind of asymptote is this?  Is this equivalent to $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1$?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that $f$ and $g$ tend to infinity as $x$ tends to infinity.

If $g$ is $C^1$ then
$$g(x+a(x))=g(x)+g'(x)a(x)+o(a(x))$$
and since $a(x)\rightarrow 0$ as $x$ tends to infinity we can write
$$g(x+a(x))=g(x)+g'(a(x))a(x)+o(1)$$
This means that
$$f(x)=g(x)+g'(a(x))a(x)+o(1)$$
that is
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1+\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{g'(a(x))a(x)}{g(x)}$$
if both sides exist. If $g'$ is continuous at 0 then $g'(a(x))\rightarrow g'(0)$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$. Since $a(x)\rightarrow 0$ and $g(x)\rightarrow\infty$ we get
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1$$

Comment: Can't accept answers so quick, and could you prove the converse, that if $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\to1$, then $a(x)\to0$?

Comment: Your proposed result is not correct. To see this, let $g(x)=e^{x^2}$ and put $a(x)=1/x$. Then $a(x)\to0$ but $g(x+1/x)/g(x)\to \exp(2)$ as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: Hmm, this seems correct Byron. Do you see where my reasoning fails?

Comment: No it is not correct. Take a closer look at your Taylor's approximation.